# Rspec throws cannot load such file error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am picking up a project I have not worked on for a year. When I try to run rspec I get this error message

```
   /home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': 
cannot load such file -- rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base (LoadError)
```

I get this message after running

```
bundle exec rspec
```

And it comes after the migrations have been executed

```
andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> rails -v
Rails 4.1.9
andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> rspec -v
3.5.4
andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]


andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> which gem activesupport
/home/andreas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem

andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> which gem active_record
/home/andreas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem

andreas@ofelia ~/w/sl2> gem list | grep activerecord
activerecord (4.1.9, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.3, 4.0.0, 3.0.10)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
```

**Solution**

It was a rspec version problem. I didn't remember that the tests was made with rspec 2. Hope someone can learn something form this

Comment: what do you get with `gem which activesupport`?

Comment: updated question

Comment: actually my bad should check `active_record` instead.

Comment: no worries, updated again

Comment: and check your AR version `gem list | grep activerecord`

Comment: Thanks, updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138279/discussion-between-edmund-lee-and-andreas-lyngstad).